# Struggling with code time extension in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just newly added the **Code Time** extension in my Visual studio code, but due to some sort of reason it is not responding, could anyone clarify about the things causing hurdle to it..?
I've added it for the first time, help me get the proper solution to it!